# Generate random Gaussian noise MTLTexture or MTLBuffer of size (width, height)

Tags: swift, random, metal

I am writing a real-time video filter application and for one of the algorithms I want to try out, I need to generate a random, gaussian univariate distributed buffer (or texture) based on the input source.

Coming from a Python background, the following few lines are running in about 0.15s (which is not real-time worthy but a lot faster than the Swift code I tried below):

```py
h = 1170
w = 2532

with Timer():
    noise = np.random.normal(size=w * h * 3)

plt.imshow(noise.reshape(w,h,3))
plt.show()
```

My Swift code try:

```swift
    private func generateNoiseTextureBuffer(width: Int, height: Int) -> [Float] {
        let w = Float(width)
        let h = Float(height)
        var noiseData = [Float](repeating: 0, count: width * height * 4)
        for xi in (0  ..< width) {
            for yi in (0  ..< height) {
                let index = yi * width + xi
                
                let x = Float(xi)
                let y = Float(yi)
                let random = GKRandomSource()
                let gaussianGenerator = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: random, mean: 0.0, deviation: 1.0)
                let randX = gaussianGenerator.nextUniform()
                let randY = gaussianGenerator.nextUniform()
                
                let scale = sqrt(2.0 * min(w, h) * (2.0 / Float.pi))
                
                let rx = floor(max(min(x + scale * randX, w - 1.0), 0.0))
                let ry = floor(max(min(y + scale * randY, h - 1.0), 0.0))
                
                noiseData[index * 4 + 0] = rx + 0.5
                noiseData[index * 4 + 1] = ry + 0.5
                noiseData[index * 4 + 2] = 1
                noiseData[index * 4 + 3] = 1
            }
        }
        return noiseData
    }

...

let noiseData = self.generateNoiseTextureBuffer(width: context.sourceColorTexture.width, height: context.sourceColorTexture.height)
let noiseDataSize = noiseData.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: noiseData[0])
self.noiseBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: noiseData, length: noiseDataSize)
```

How can I accomplish this fast and easily in Swift?

Comment: You are recreating your source and distribution each iteration for some reason

Comment: Thank you! I put the generator initialisation outside of the loop but it is still running very slow. I also tried utilising `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` but still, not much gain.

Comment: What exactly is very slow? I just copy-pasted the code into a swift repl and got a `0.137106083 seconds` runtime for 512x512 noise texture buffer. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Use one of the 2 implementations of MPSMatrixRandom: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsmatrixrandom